# Check this value of $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^m}{(x-t)^\alpha}dt$

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, beta-function

I want to prove that:

> $$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^m}{(x-t)^\alpha}dt=\frac{\Gamma(1-\alpha)\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(m-\alpha+2)}x^{m-\alpha+1}$$ where $m$ is a positive integer and $\alpha \in [0,1]$.

I try to prove this formula with 
$\beta(x,y)=\dfrac{\beta(x)\beta(y)}{\beta(x+y)}$ and definition of $\Gamma$ function but i can't and confused!

Comment: $\frac{t^m}{(x-t)^{\alpha}}=x^{m-\alpha}\frac{\left(\frac{t}{x}\right)^m}{\left(1-\frac{t}{x}\right)^{\alpha}}$. Then use the substitution $u=\frac{t}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Doing what @vnd suggested, you have $$\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{t^m}{(x-t)^\alpha}dt=x^{-\alpha +m+1}\int_{0}^{1}u^m (1-u)^{-\alpha }\,du $$ and $$\int u^m (1-u)^{-\alpha }\,du= B_u(m+1,1-\alpha )$$ where appears the incomplete beta function.

Now, consider the bounds and the relation to the gamma function.